# Unable to load popup - please try again

Tags: support, flags, popups

I noticed this when trying to flag posts:

1. Click on `flag`;
2. I changed my mind, and being the lazy one, I tapped the `Esc` key, the popup disappeared;
3. I changed my mind again, and now I click on the `flag` link:

[image]

Note this is predictable: If I click it again, the popup would load; press `Esc` again, then it again breaks down.

Also, if I use `Esc` to get rid of the picture above, then next time I click it same would happen. But if I use `Esc` one more time, it returns to normal.

Is this a tricky bug or something?

Thanks!

Comment: [Ironic.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ahf08.jpg)

Comment: @Won't: lololol nice

Comment: Apparently the fact that stackoverflow doesn't gracefully recover from an aborted ajax request is a support request, rather than a bug...?

Answer (score 3):

When you press escape during AJAX request, Stack Overflow's javascript show you error because you aborted AJAX request.

Next time you click it, there is another AJAX call and it should work normally

Comment: So this is more an issue of AJAX?

Comment: It isn't issue. AJAX is aborted if you press Esc. IN case that AJAX aborts, StackOverflow throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

As @gensis notes, this is an AJAX request.  Try the following:

1. Click 'flag'.
2. Wait a few seconds (until the '...' next to the **flag** link disappears).
3. Close the dialogue with the 'x' or <kbd>Esc</kbd> or the cancel link.
4. Click 'flag' again.

If you wait long enough, it should work using any of the three methods.
Using **any of these three methods** to close the dialog *before it has completely loaded* will cause the same notification you see above.

That said, if you dismiss the notification and click flag a third time, it *should* work again.  Hence the **please try again**.  Experimenting here for a few minutes, I believe it is working-by-design because you interrupted the AJAX request.  The second click clears the AJAX error.  The third click correctly re-opens the dialog.

Comment: Great! Seems that I am too impatient:)

Comment: As are we all.  :O)

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of this, that I've just experienced, is a Proxy Auto-Configuration script for redirecting advertising URLs whose pattern matching rules just happen to match the URLs that StackExchange uses for flagging posts.  The behaviour is slightly different, in that retrying the request will never succeed.

The `re_banner` regular expression in [John LoVerso's "no ads" PAC script](http://schooner.com./~loverso/no-ads/) matches StackExchange's post flagging mechanism.  It's the `*/popup/*?_=*` form of the StackExchange URL that does it.

Any advertising removal PAC script or HTTP proxy that has a similar regular expression for recognizing popup advertising will block StackExchange's flagging mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I had to disable Privoxy 3.0.18 before the `flag` functionality would work.